# Shopify search.liquid pagination broken

Tags: search, pagination, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to display the full 50 products that Shopify allows per page call, but in my search results only 10 items are displayed and the pagination links lead to the same 10 products for  each page.

I've read through the documentation and even used the template from Caroline Schnapp's skeleton theme here: https://github.com/Shopify/skeleton-theme/blob/master/templates/search.liquid, I get the same results no matter what I try.

To summarise, I'd like to display 50 products and pagination links on my search results page.

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Here's the contents of my `search.liquid` template:

```
{% paginate search.results by 50 %}

{% if search.results_count == 0 %}

  <div class="search-noresults">
      <h2 class="no-results">Nothing found for <span class="search-terms">{{ search.terms }}</span></h2>
      <p class="search-again">try searching again</p>
  </div>

{% else %}
  <section class="search-grid clearfix">
    <h2 class="results-for">Results for <span class="search-terms">{{ search.terms }}</span></h2>

    {% for product in search.results %}
      <section class="collection-grid ">
                <div class="product-box" href="{{product.url}}">
                    <a href="{{product.url}}" class="ajaxify-link"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large'}}" alt="{{ product.description | strip_html | truncate: 75 }} click for more information" /></a>
                <hr class="collection-hr"><span class="grid-title">{{product.title}}</span><br/><span class="grid-price">{{ product.price | divided_by: 100 | replace: '.',' ' | truncatewords: 1 | remove: '...' }} £</span>
                </div>
      </section>
    {% endfor %}
  </section>

  {% if search.results_count > 50 %}
    <div id="pagination">
        {{ paginate | default_pagination }}
    </div>

{% endif %}

{% endif %}


{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that all I needed to do was to activate the shop and the pagination worked as normal, when the shop is in dev mode pagination doesn't work as expected. Hopefully this helps someone else out there as I didn't find any of that in the documentation.